# Qual melhor índice MySql

Tags: mysql, índices

Olá estou com uma duvida sobre explain, index no mysql

Tabela de Imóveis 47.240
Tabela de Ordem de Atendimento 1.887.421

```
SELECT
    SQL_NO_CACHE
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    imoveis I
    INNER JOIN situacao_cod_venda SCV   ON SCV.flag_mostra_site     = 1 AND SCV.id  = I.situacao_codigo_venda
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 
            id 
        FROM 
            ordem_atendimento_envio OAE 
        WHERE 
            I.data_alt_sit_ven = OAE.data_ultima_alteracao_situacao AND 
            OAE.id_imovel = I.id AND 
            OAE.id_ordem_atendimento = '69451' 
    )
```

quando crio o index para id_imovel da tabela ordem de atendimento o explain me mostra 9438 e a consulta demora 5 segundos

quando crio o index para id_ordem_atendimento da tabela ordem de atendimento o explain me mostra 478 e a consulta demora 15 segundos

na tabela de imoveis no explain ambos retorna 48253

quando crio um index composto id_imovel, id_ordem_atendimento a respsta é instantanea, não da nenhum segundo 0,412 milesimos de segundos, porem o explain mostra 9438.

Gostaria de saber pq o index que ficou menor ficou mais lento?
Qual a regra para verificar as linhas checadas ex:
explain 
table imoveis rows 48253
table ordem atendimento rows 478

então rows checadas é 48253*478 = 23.064.934 (seria isso?)

O que sifinifica quando ref sai null, ou const

veja o vídeo abaixo que exemplifiquei detalhadamente.

[Comportamento do MySql, não faz sentido (VÍDEO NO VIMEO)](https://vimeo.com/191351899)

indice com menos registro, mais lento.

Abraços

Comment: Acho que compreendi sua critica. Conseguiria publicar o DDL destas duas tabelas para que possamos melhor ajudar?

Comment: Fabio, você conseguiu assistir o vídeo?

Comment: O melhor índice é que torna as suas leituras mais rápidas sem fazer com que a escrita se torne um gargá-lo. A quantidade de `rows` no comando `EXPLAIN` é uma estimativa (para tabelas InnoDB). No caso da sua consulta a parte cara buscar o `id_movel` na tabela `ordem_atendimento_envio` para cada linha da consulta na tabela `imovel`. O índice em `id_imovel` resolve isso. O índice composto com `id_ordem_atendimento` garante acesso rápido à todas ordens de cada imóvel, restando assim apenas cruzar as datas em um data set mínimo.